# Java Swing: positioning dialog on top of existing window

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Can someone show simple Java Swing code/web resource that will position the popup dialog center-aligned on top of an existing JFrame window when the JFrame's button clicked?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Oh..it's pretty simple:

Say you have a JFrame that contains a JDialog, and you want the JDialog (when opened) to be right on top of JFrame.

So in JDialog constructor, you should have something like:

```
public class MyDialog extends JDialog 
public MyDialog(JFrame parent) 
{
    super.setLocationRelativeTo(parent); // this will do the job
}
```

In other words, pass JFrame pointer to your dialog, and call setLocationRelativeTo(...); method.

Comment: I didn't realize that method existed; pretty handy!

Comment: Wow, this really helped me out! Small detail though... it should be called only AFTER setting your dialog size, or the dialog will appear with its top left corner centered on the parent window.

Comment: how can I find the parent referenced here ?

Answer (score 4):

I usually call the following method:

```
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
```

[Link to Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component))

Comment: how can I find the parent referenced here ?

Answer (score 3):

What kind of popup dialog are you talking about?  If you're using a JOptionPane or something similar, set its parent component to the JFrame and it will automatically center on top of the JFrame window.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello, World!");
```

If you are creating your own JDialog, you can get the JFrame's position using JFrame.getLocation() and its size using JFrame.getSize().  The math is pretty straightforward from there; just compute the center of the JFrame and subtract half the width/height of the JDialog to get your dialog's upper left corner.

If your JDialog has not been rendered yet, JFrame.getSize() might give you a zero size.  In that case, you can use JDialog.getPreferredSize() to find out how big it will be once it's rendered on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a modal and centered dialog on a window ...

In the dialog's constructor:

```
class CustomDialog extends JDialog {
    public CustomDialog(Frame owner, String title, boolean modal) {
        super(owner, title, modal);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

        ...

        setSize(150, 100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
    }
}
```

To display the dialog (using a button, etc.):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```