# Java Swing Main Window comes to the front automatically when opening a dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a Java Swing Application where a JDialog is opened upon clicking on a JMenu in the Menubar, but for some reason, the main JFrame automatically comes to the front as soon as the JDialog opens.

I simply open the Dialog in the MenuListener of the JMenu.

```
@Override
public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.setVisible(true);    
}
```

The main JFrame is started here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fenster hauptFenster = new Fenster();
            hauptFenster.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I already tried calling `toFront()` on the JDialog upon creation, but that doesn't help it.

Here's a minimal reproducible example where the problem occurs:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    
    JFrame thisFrame;
    
    public Test() {
        //GUI
        setTitle("Behaviour Test");
        setSize(350,200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        thisFrame = this;
        
        
        //Menübar
        JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu widerstand = new JMenu("Start Dialog");
        widerstand.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
                TestDialog dialog = new TestDialog(thisFrame);
                dialog.setVisible(true);    
            }
            @Override
            public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
            }
            
        });

        menu.add(widerstand);
        setJMenuBar(menu);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test testFrame = new Test();
                testFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class TestDialog extends JDialog {

    public TestDialog(JFrame parent) {
        setTitle("Test Dialog");
        setSize(450,300);
        super.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no trick to display a child dialog. It should always appear on top of the parent frame. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates problem. So you need a JFrame with a menu. And you need an ActionListener that creates and displays the frame. The frame should be set as the parent of the dialog. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test to see the described behaviour.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677318/java-swing-positioning-dialog-on-top-of-existing-window

Comment: @parhamdamavandi: That doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: @camickr I added it

Comment: I've never tried display a dialog from a MenuListener before. I guess the issue is that the frame is requesting focus after the menu event is executed. JMen@Madv0x *The frame should be set as the parent of the dialog.* - where do you do that?

Comment: @camickr Updated, but the problem still occurs. How can I stop the frame from requesting focus?

Comment: You have to actually pass the parent frame to the constructor of the JDialog.

Comment: @weisj Oh my god, you're right. Thank you so much. I just had to put `super(parent);` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to set the parent of the dialog as I originally suggested in my comment (since this is the normal way to keep the parent/child relationship between the frame/dialog).

However, even if you don't set the parent, I have not seen this behaviour. Maybe that is because I have always displayed a child dialog from within an `ActionListener`.

So, it is interesting that the behaviour is different between the `MenuListener` and an `ActionListener` if you don't set the parent.

When using the `MenuListener` you need to wrap the code in an `invokeLater()`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    JFrame thisFrame;

    public Test() {
        //GUI
        setTitle("Behaviour Test");
        setSize(350,200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        thisFrame = this;


        JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu widerstand = new JMenu("Start Dialog");
        widerstand.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        TestDialog dialog2 = new TestDialog(thisFrame);
                        dialog2.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
            }

        });

        menu.add(widerstand);
        setJMenuBar(menu);

        JButton button = new JButton("Display Dialog");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener((e) ->
        {
            TestDialog dialog2 = new TestDialog(thisFrame);
            dialog2.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Test testFrame = new Test();
                testFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class TestDialog extends JDialog {

    public TestDialog(JFrame parent) {
        setTitle("Test Dialog");
        setSize(450,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Works as expected with the `ActionListener`.